# How to get the values of a checkbox in after trigger in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a form for creating new events in Oracle Apex. With that form I am able to create new events just fine. But at the bottom of that form is a checkbox where the user will specify the clubs that are involved in organizing the event.

[image]

The list of values for the checkbox which you can see at the bottom of the image above is set to a sql query which selects 'club_name' and 'club_id' from 'club' table.

[image]

Now what i want to do is after the events gets successfully created,  the club_id of the checked clubs with the id of the newly created event needs to be inserted into the 'club_event' junction table which related each event with their organizing club. So for that I thought of creating after trigger on events table. But I couldn't find how can I access the id's of the club selected in the plsql code. So my question is how my I do so and is my approach for relating event with organizing club fine? Thank you.

With the suggestiong from "Koen" I tried to I tries to implement it through "Process". But I am having problem in making my script work.

```
DECLARE
    type idarray IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(10);
    ids idarray;
BEGIN
    ids := apex_string.split(:P72_CLUBS, ':');
    FOR id IN ids LOOP
        INSERT INTO club_event
        VALUES(id, P72_EVENT_ID);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

What are the things that I am doing wrong and how may I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a trigger for that. Use a page process instead. The values of the page item (I assume that is P1_CLUB) will be passed on page submit as a colon separated list of return values (in your case club_id). Use [apex_string.split](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6) to convert the colon separated list to a pl/sql array . Loop through the array and insert/update/delete the records in/from the clubs table .

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested and I am having problem in writing the script. I have updated my question to include the script I have written. Can you help me in with that script? Also I have written it in "Server-side Condition" section by selecting "When Button Pressed" as "Create" and "Type" as "PL/SQL Function Body". Am I doing it right?

Comment: Hello Samman "PL/SQL Function body" is not available for page processes. Are you sure you are choosing a "Page Process". This is not going to be answered in one reply from me and it is no longer relevant to the original question. Also, asking following up questions are direct to a single user and not to the StackOverflow community. I would suggest posting a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Koen's answer, if you want to view the event and also want to populate the checkbox with the checked values, you will have to set the following attributes for the checkbox page item:

1. Source - Type = SQL Query (return colon separated value)
2. SQL Query = select club_id from my_club_to_event_table where event_id = :P1_EVENT_ID
3. Used = Always, replacing any existing value in session state

Assuming P1_EVENT_ID is the primary key page item on that page.